# Kendo grid virtual scroll stopping at certain point even through more elements are available in the DOM

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I currently have about 1 million records been paged and added into the Kendo grid. When I scroll to the bottom of the grid in Chrome it correctly calculates all the pages and the last page of data is displayed correctly. However in IE 11, Edge and Firefox the scroll stops at around 600000 records. More nodes are in the DOM however these can not be reached because the scroll is at the bottom of the container and i'm unable to scroll any further.

```
    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            pageSize: 1000,
            serverPaging: true,
            transport: {
                dataType: 'json',
                read: (e) => {
                    //....... Stuff to get data goes here
                    e.success({data: data, total: total});
                    });                     
                }

            },
            schema: {
                total: (response) => {
                    //console.log('response for total');
                    //console.log(response.total);
                    return response.total;
                },
                data: (response) => {
                    //console.log('response for data');
                    //console.log(response.data);
                    return response.data;
                },
            }
        },
        columns: [{
                field: 'FieldOne',
                filterable: false
        }, {
                field: 'FieldTwo',
                filterable: false               
        }],
        height: 700,
        scrollable: {
            virtual: true
        },
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: false

    });
```

I can't see a clear solution for this as it works in chrome just fine. Does anybody have any idea of why this would be happening?

Thanks

Comment: You might have to settle for paging. Check [this response](http://www.telerik.com/forums/virtual-scrolling-issues) from Telerik. He explains the more rows you have the more stressed the browser will get until it finally gives up. Test [Telerik's example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-local-data) in different browsers to see the issue occur..

Comment: @Supersnake I did see that forum post and I was hopeful that things may have changed in the last 3 years or so. but yeah just run the example in other browsers and seeing the same issue, well they have limited to 200000 in IE which I took to meaning that something is not right, Thanks.